# How to exit the loop and print a statement when the sum of two integers in an array is not equal to zero

Tags: java

Am trying to store and print an array whose sum of two integers in the given array is equal to zero. But when there are no two integers whose sum is equal to zero, am unable to exit the loop and print "There are no two integers whose sum is zero" . Please let me know how to solve this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] origArr = { 1, 2, 3, -6, 8, 4 };
        for (int i = 0; i < origArr.length; i++) {
            int firstNumber = origArr[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < origArr.length; j++) {
                int secondNumber = origArr[j];
                if (firstNumber + secondNumber == 0) {
                    int[] newArr = new int[2];
                    newArr[0] = firstNumber;
                    newArr[1] = secondNumber;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));

                }

                else {

                    System.out.println("There are no two integers whose sum is zero ");

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

when the 'If' condition is not satisfied, system is printing the sopln multiple times as long as the loop is iterating.

Comment: use a boolean flag. Hint: if there are none, that means every elements has been checked, so the loop is over.

Comment: Your logic check 

"when there are no two integers whose sum is equal to zero" 

is incorrect.

You should store the result somewhere else and then print it only after iterating throughout the arrays.

Comment: @SimonPham If OP only wants to print all matching combinations, I don't see what's wrong in this logic

Comment: @jhamon the wrong thing is he print System.out.println("There are no two integers whose sum is zero "); whenever it found a pair which firstNumber + secondNumber != 0

Comment: @SimonPham I believe that was the point of the OP's question.  The statement is clearly in the wrong place and should only be printed when no two such numbers have been found, after the OP leaves the loop. Otherwise, print those that *have* been found.  Hence the boolean solution.

Comment: The only problem with the logic is the limit on the outer loop should be `origArr.length-1`. And I would opt not to put the values in an internal array but just print them as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no couple of integers matching your condition, that means you have already check all the possible combinations in your array.

If you have check all the combinations, that means both loops are terminated.

The "no solution" print should be done after the two loops. To know if you need to print it or not, you can use a boolean. Setting it to true when any matching combination is found:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] origArr = { 1, 2, 3, -6, 8, 4 };
    boolean solutionFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < origArr.length-1; i++) {
        int firstNumber = origArr[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < origArr.length; j++) {
            int secondNumber = origArr[j];
            if (firstNumber + secondNumber == 0) {
                // set the flag to true
                solutionFound = true;
                System.out.println(firstNumber + ", " + secondNumber);
            }
        }
    }
    // check the flag to see if a solution was found
    if (!solutionFound) {
        System.out.println("There are no two integers whose sum is zero ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you .This is working correctly. Not sure what's wrong in my question(i know I have put print statement in the wrong place), someone downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Nother one with some Logging to and and a Positive found in the Array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] origArr = { 1, 2, 3, -6, 8, 4 , -4 };
    boolean foundit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < origArr.length; i++) {
        int firstNumber = origArr[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < origArr.length; j++) {
            int secondNumber = origArr[j];
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(firstNumber));
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(secondNumber));
            if (firstNumber + secondNumber == 0) {
                int[] newArr = new int[2];
                newArr[0] = firstNumber;
                newArr[1] = secondNumber;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
                System.out.println("Found !!!!!");
                foundit = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (foundit == false) {
            System.out.println("There are no two integers whose sum is zero ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `stream` solution demonstrates:

- A different approach to finding solutions.
- As well as correctly printing when there are none.

It basically does a nested loop using a pair of `Intstreams` and creates a stream of arrays holding values to be tested.  The `flatMap` combines the stream of streams into one and then the arrays are filtered based on the sum of their elements.  These are then collected into a `list`.  All solutions are then printed.  If the list is empty, an appropriate message is printed.

```
        int len = origArr.length;
        List<int[]> list = IntStream.range(0, len - 1)
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, len)
                .mapToObj(j -> new int[] { origArr[i], origArr[j] }))
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .filter(a -> a[0] + a[1] == 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(
                    "There are no two integers whose sum is zero ");
        } else {
            list.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
        }
    }
```